# DELETE row FROM MYTABLE in 1 week from today

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I try to delete a row in my DDB in 1 week.

I wrote:

```
<?php
//in my page
//On click
$today=date("Ymd");
$query = 'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (id,val,date),("", "'.$val.'", "'.$today'")';
dbb_exe($query);
?>

<?php
//in my header
//Check my table
$today=date("Ymd");

$query = 'SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE id=.'(int)$_GET['id'];
$r_date = dbb_exe($query);

//Here it's where i want delete my row if the row exists since 1 week

if($r_date==($today - "1week")){
//DELETE row
$query = 'DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id=.'(int)$_GET['id];
dbb_exe($query);
}


?>
```

As you see i don t know how to calcul the var "1week",

right now i m reading strtotime to try something like $date= strtotime($today);
but i m lost , anyyway i have all the day(+night) to success

Red bull and stackoverflow are my friends.

Thanks to the community

Have a nice day

Mel

Comment: Have a look at all the [mysql date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Top tip: almost every week I know has 7 days.

Comment: won't help with the week calculation, but you have `WHERE id=.'(int)$_GET['id'];` in two places, I think you should change these both to `WHERE id='.(int)$_GET['id'];` (the '.' is on the wrong side of the quote mark)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing all work with php, I believe you can try something like:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This should delete all records from `mytable` with `date` equals to the 1 week ago.

Replace `=` to `<` if you want to delete all records older than 1 week.

Comment: there is no check on the `id=.'(int)$_GET['id];`

Comment: Right, my fault. Please try DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and id = $id

Answer (score 0):

change `if($r_date==($today - "1week")){` to 
`if($r_date ==(date('Ymd', strtotime(date('Ymd') . " -7days"))) {`

Answer (score 0):

use: if($today - $r_date >= 7)

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing DATES in your `mysql` as `DATE` data type then do the following:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date_column = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You haven't provided much details so in above answer I assumed that it stored as `date` already, current date will be automatically picked up by `MySQL`, however, you want to add 7 days to any specific date then change `CURRENT_DATE()` to the required date in the format like `2012-09-20`